# How can I frame a bookshelf like this?

Tags: framing, shelving

Looking through the Houzz iPad app this weekend, I came across this

[image]

I want this. Got the wife's approval and I'm thinking about starting it this weekend (gutting the old fireplace / bookshelves and starting the electrical / structured cabling)

I was originally thinking about using 2x6's as they look like the size of the structural pieces, but now I'm thinking 1x2's to frame it out and drywall over.

Mine will be deeper as I want the components under the TV to be on the shelf and not on what looks like a separate insert.

Or do the masses think it was done with wood (real or engineered) and just painted white?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd frame it out and then clad with paint-grade MDF. That seems a lot easier than trying to tape and mud all those outside drywall corners.

Also...be sure to keep the center compartment big enough so you can continue to upgrade the size of your TV. ;)